# How to apply timer based throb or pulse or fade-away effects to an image in IPhone or iOS?

Tags: iphone, core-animation

This is a multi-part question:

1. How can one create an animation-block and hook it up with a timer such that the animation block runs when the image is put on display in the iPhone?
2. How can any one of the following three effects be applied to an image?

   1. throb effect
   2. pulse effect (same thing as throb as far as I can guess)
   3. fade-away or fade-out effect

Answer (score 0):

Apply the size or alpha transforms to your image within the animation block, and then create a callback function (called after the animation is complete) that calls a function that applies the opposite animated transform to your image.  Then the callback for that function will start the cycle again, and so on.

Comment: Could you point to the code that works towards size based animation alterations to the UIImageView?